# Javascript Drop Down New issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

So Basically, I have this code which selects a drop down menu option, and presses it. I need it to press the first option and then press the second option.

```
var x = document.getElementById("product-select").options;
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i].text=="34"){
            x[i].selected=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("here")[0].click();
            break;
   }
}
```

how do I know make this press text 34, and then press 36 ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "how do I know make this press text 34, and then press 36 ?" you need to make your question clearer

Comment: I'm not sure why you need it, but if you're looking for automation in UI testing, have a look at Coded UI testing or tools like Selenium.

Comment: Hello, My question is clear, I believe. At the moment when this code is loaded it opens a dropbox, and presses number 34. I want it now to go back and press number 36 from the drop down option.

@RickvandenBosch Is Selenium any good ? Or can't this code be slightly edited to get a response?

Answer (score 0):

You've also added jquery to your tags, so:

```
$('#product-select').val(34);
```

Answer (score 0):

Again: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish. But the included example has a dropdown, and has JavaScript to iterate through the options. With this, I think you will be able to create a solution for the question you have.

```js
var index = 0;

function SelectNext() {
  var x = document.getElementById("product-select");
  if (index < x.options.length - 1) {
    index++;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
  x.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

```html
<select id="product-select">
  <option value=1>One</option>
  <option value=2>Two</option>
  <option value=3>Three</option>
  <option value=4>Four</option>
  <option value=5>Five</option>
</select>
<input type='button' onclick='SelectNext()' value='Click me'></input>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is still wrong, Basically. I have a website where I want In my original code it selects a dropdown option, with this new one I want it to select more than one drop down option :)